# json parsing errors "NullPointerException"

Tags: java, json, parsing

I got error **NullPointerException** in Java.

I am just using `JSONParser`

String test is

```
{
    "processGroupRevision": {
        "clientId":"f98f0e63-0164-1000-6c10-442b4b1fbe8f",
        "version":1
        },
        "variableRegistry":{
            "variables": [{
                "variable": {
                    "name":"123123123",
                    "value":"12322",
                    "pr": "..." 
                }
            }]
        }
}
```

And here is the main ***Code***

```
String test = sb.toString();
System.out.println(test);

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(test);
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObj.get("variable");

System.out.println("==================");

for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.size(); i++) {
    JSONObject tempObj = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
    System.out.println(""+(i+1)+" key : " + tempObj.get("name"));
    System.out.println(""+(i+1)+" value : " + tempObj.get("value"));
}
```

How can I fix this problem? 
Is it in the **For loop** ?

Comment: The `...` doesn't look like valid JSON anyway...?

Comment: typo *variables* vs *variable*

Comment: `variable` and `variables` are too deep within the hierarchy. You need to start from `variableRegistry`. Also as @Jens said you're looking for `variables` since you're attempting to retrieve the array.

Comment: jsonObj.get("variable") -- Does your jsonObj have the property "variable" ?

Comment: @ko_ma - about the duplicate closure: Read it, apply to the program, then ask a more specific question such as "why `jsonObj.get("variable")` returns `null`".